# Find letters in a column which are unique in comparison to several other columns and count them in segments

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genetics

I am a bit struggling to code a script on R to process a dataset to get an input file for another program.

I have a dataset looking like this:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
chr  pos ind0 ind1 ind2 ind3 ind4 ind5 ind6 ind7 ind8 ind9 ind10
MRVK01001299.1 972    C    C    T    N    C    C    T    N    N    C     C
MRVK01001299.1 973    G    G    G    N    G    G    G    N    N    G     G
MRVK01001299.1 997    C    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T     T
MRVK01001299.1 999    A    T    T    N    T    T    T    T    T    T     T
MRVK01001299.1 1018   A    C    T    N    T    C    C    T    T    T     T
MRVK01001299.1 1086   A    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T     T
MRVK01001299.1 2125   C    C    T    N    C    C    T    N    N    C     C
MRVK01001299.1 2456   G    G    G    N    G    G    G    N    N    G     G
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to identify the position (pos) for which letters are found uniquely in ind0.

“N”s would not be counted as a different letters. So for example, we would have a unique value for position 997, 999 and 1086.

Then, I would like to count how many times ind0 has a private letters in series of 1000 for the position (pos) column.
So this would be:

```
0 2 
1000 1
2000 0
etc
```

Because we have two positions with a unique value for ind0 between 0 and 1000, 1 between 1000 and 2000, 0 between 2000 and 3000. The furthest value will be above 20,000,000.

I am struggling to find a solution to code this on R. Would someone be able to help?

Comment: It would maybe make it easier to answer if we know more about the data, and what is the biological question, expected output meaning? Added some tags, hoping users with "dolphins" data have some insight.

Comment: use `dput()` on the table (or subset of table) you included, and post the result in here. This allows us to copy your table.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered made the data reproducible.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. The data is the scaffold, position and then the allele (A, T, C, G, N) found in each of the individuals. I am comparing one particular individual (ind01) to the other to see if he has clusters of private alleles. If so, this may indicate he has ancestry from a population we have not sampled (ghost population). The individuals are dolphins and the chrm and pos columns indicate the position in the bottlenose dolphin reference genome.

Comment: This is the resut of dput() on the first 8 rows (out of 43,500) of my dataset for the first 3 individuals (there are 22 individuals):

Comment: structure(list(chr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "MRVK01001299.1", class = "factor"), pos = c(1972L, 
1973L, 2097L, 8281L, 8357L, 8653L, 8746L, 9255L), ind0 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G", "N", "T"
), class = "factor"), ind1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G", "N", "T"), class = "factor"), 
    ind2 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
    "C", "G", "N", "T"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
8L))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare value of ind0 to other individuals, and subset:

```
res1 <- df1[ rowSums(df1$ind0 == df1[, -c(1:3)]) == 0 &
                       apply(df1[, -c(1:3)], 1, function(i) length(unique(i[ i != "N" ]))) == 1, ]

res1
#              chr  pos ind0 ind1 ind2 ind3 ind4 ind5 ind6 ind7 ind8 ind9 ind10
# 3 MRVK01001299.1  997    C    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T     T
# 4 MRVK01001299.1  999    A    T    T    N    T    T    T    T    T    T     T
# 6 MRVK01001299.1 1086    A    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T     T
```

Then we can get counts per chunks using *table*:

```
table(cut(res1$pos, c(0, 1000, 2000, 3000)))
# (0,1e+03] (1e+03,2e+03] (2e+03,3e+03] 
#         2             1             0
```

Comment: Many thanks for your very fast reply. I tried it but I get the following error which I haven't managed to solve yet.  Error in df1$ind0 == df1[, -c(1:3)] : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.data.frame(x) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.data.frame") for "=="
2: In df1$ind0 == df1[, -c(1:3)] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Also I would like row 1018 not to be included as some individuals have a different letters. But 999 would be included as the only different letter for the other individual is a N. Sorry I did not mention N means missing data for that individual at that position.

Comment: @mariels17 Error because ind columns are factor, change them to character or set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when importing into R.

Comment: @mariels17 edited the post, now result doesn't include 1018.

Comment: @zx87754 Thanks again for your help. Unfortunately, it seems the input file with just the count of the position is not enough and I also would like to print the position of the private alleles.

So the output would look like:
0 2 997,999
1000 1 1086
2000 0
etc

I have been trying to find the solution on forums but did not find anything relevant.
Would you or anyone be able to help?

Thank you very much

Comment: @mariels17 please post a new question with representative example data and expected output.

Comment: Thanks I will do that